# Having trouble regarding inheritence & utilising attributes in different classes

Tags: java, class, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I am new to Stack Overflow & Java, and I am having trouble figuring out a way to make a class that utilizes attributes from two other classes. It doesn't need all the attributes just select ones.

I have a house, town and a person class. Where house needs the town name from town and name & `phNumber` from person.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Town {
    protected String name;
    private int postCode;

    public Town (String tName , int tCode){
        name = tName;
        postCode = tCode;

    }

    public String getName(String name){
        return name;
    }

    public int getCode(int postCode){
        return postCode;
    }
```

And the person class:

```
public class Person {
    protected String pName;
    private long pNumber;

    public Person (String name,long number){
        pName = name;
        pNumber = number;
    }

    public String getPersonName(String name){
        return pName;
    }

    public long getNumber(long number){
        return pNumber;
    }

    public void setNumber(long newNumber){  
        pNumber = newNumber;
    }
```

And my house class:

```
public class House extends Person, Town {

    public House(String address , String name, int code , String pName,     Long pNumber) {
        this.name = Person.pName;

    }
}
```

But as you can see I can't seem to get the house class to do what I want, and after searching through online resources cant find much help on the matter. Any pointers in the correct direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: _"as you can see I can't seem to get the house class to do what I want"_ ... actually we can't see.  What do you mean?

Comment: You also have a 'bug' in you `getName()` etc.  They just return the value that is passed as argument instead of the field value of the object.

Comment: What i meant by "as you can see..." is that house class is currently incomplete because iam having trouble with it.

Comment: A house wouldn't extend a the behaviour of a Person. For example a house would extend the behavouir of a building or a Car would extend the behavouir of a vehicle.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in my question guys, bear with me. The situation is as follows :  There is Town(Town Name, PostCode), within town will be House(Address, Town Name Etc.) The House is owned by a person, so the owners name will be a field for House also. If that makes any sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First question: **What would you like to use and how**? You should make your classes reflect stuff that has meaning, that makes it easier to think of how to create and use them.

For example a `House` could be in a `Town` and contain a `Person`

```
public class House
{
    private Town    inTown;
    private Person  owner;

    public House (Town inTown, Person owner)
    {
        this.inTown = inTown;
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    public String getTownName()
    {
        return this.inTown.getName();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you really only care about the names:

```
public class House
{
    private String  townName;
    private String  ownerName;

    public House (Town inTown, Person owner)
    {
        this.townName = inTown.getName();
        this.ownerName = owner.getName();
    }
    public String getTownName()
    {
        return this.townName;
    }
}
```

If memory is not a problem, I would advice the first solution, as it is easier to extend and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your help. HOUSE needs to have the name from TOWN, and needs to have the name and number from PERSON.

Answer (score 6):

House can't extend both Person and Town. Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance.

And it doesn't make sense anyway. A House is not a Person and a House is not a Town.

Composition would make more sense - a House contains a Person (or Perhaps multiple Persons) and is located in a Town.

For example :

```
public class House {

    private Person person;
    private Town town;

    public House(String address , String name, int code , String pName, Long pNumber) 
    {
        this.Town = new Town (name, code);
        this.person = new Person (pName, pNumber);
    }
}
```

However, it would probably make more sense to pass `Person` and `Town` instances to the `House` constructor, since there can be multiple Houses all in the same Town, so it makes sense for them to share the same Town instance.

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
How would i use these two classes for this other class? I have read about interfaces but am unsure whether its what i should be doing.

Comment: @30088121: You need to look at composition (has a) as opposed to inheritance (is a). In your case, a `House` object will have a `Person` object, which I presume denotes the owner and a `Town` object, which I presume would be to locality.

Comment: Thanks for your help. HOUSE needs to have the name from TOWN, and needs to have the name and number from PERSON.                                            Basically, the person owns a house, and the house is in a town.

Answer (score 2):

Java is has **single inheritance**. You can't extends from two classes.

What you can do is implements two interfaces.

Or better you can add two fields of type `Town` and `Person` to your `House`.

```
public class House {
    private Town town;
    private Person person;

    public House(Town town, Person person) {
        this.town = town;
        this.person = person;
        // Now you can use town and person attributes (if they are public or if they are exposed with getter and setter)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help mate, ill have a look into interfaces.